# My image slider is not working on my wordpress based website theme used is FOX?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, slider

I have my WordPress based website URL https://www.a2dweb.com/tech/ there is a slider on the top. A day before I merge all js and CSS into single file by combining them with the plugin css and js optimizer, after that I started facing this problem.
Please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

The ID's must be unique in document, and you are duplicating them:

In slide:

```
<article id="post-7950" class="post-slider post-7950 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-tech-facts tag-amazon-ceo tag-amazon-share-price tag-bill-gates tag-bill-gates-net-worth tag-jeff-bezos-net-worth tag-microsoft tag-richest-man tag-richest-man-in-the-world tag-stock tag-the-worlds-billionaires tag-top-richest-people-in-the-world tag-who-is-the-richest-man-in-the-world tag-world-richest-man tag-worlds-richest-man">
```

Below the slide:

```
<article id="post-7950" class="post-grid post-7950 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-tech-facts tag-amazon-ceo tag-amazon-share-price tag-bill-gates tag-bill-gates-net-worth tag-jeff-bezos-net-worth tag-microsoft tag-richest-man tag-richest-man-in-the-world tag-stock tag-the-worlds-billionaires tag-top-richest-people-in-the-world tag-who-is-the-richest-man-in-the-world tag-world-richest-man tag-worlds-richest-man"><div class="grid-inner">
```

Change the ID for divs in slider, maybe something like slide-####